# How do I pass a C# object to another class that does not inherit from it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Data class where I store certain values like State, Initials, etc.

I have a get/set for these values.

It's a windows form app, so I made another view sort of like this

```
   public partial class Actions : Form
    {
        public Actions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testLabel.Text = ;
        }
    }
```

So just as a test case I want to set this labels .Text value to my string from Data which is just like

```
class Data
{
public string State { get; set; }
public string Initials { get; set; }


public Data()
{

}
}
```

Data is being set like this from the home class

```
  Data dat = new Data();
            dat.State = "IN";
```

I saw that online the best way to do this is pass it as a value, but I'm not sure of the best way to go about this.

Comment: Can you show the code for `Data`?  Also, where is `Data` being created?

Comment: @rory.ap I updated my question to include the data class.

Comment: @rory.ap Data is being created from a Home class like (updated question)

Answer (score 3):

If you need `State` available on form load event, then best way is passing state value (or your `Data` object if you need more than just state string) to form's constructor:

```
    public Actions(string state) // or public Actions(Data data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        State = state;
    }
```

Then

```
    private void Actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testLabel.Text = State;
    }
```

Comment: I would rather pass the object than the string, how would I do that?

Comment: @rohanharrison `public Actions(Data data)` and then you can assign state  `State = data.State;` or you can store passed data as filed of form and use it later

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
public partial class Actions : Form
{
    private Data myData;
    public Actions()
    {
        myData = new Data();
        myData.State = "California";
        //the best state :D\\
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testLabel.Text = myData.State;
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
public partial class Actions : Form
{
    private Data myData;
    public Actions(Data otherDataObject)
    {
        myData = otherDataObject;
        testLabel.Text = myData.State; //here
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testLabel.Text = myData.State; //or here
    }
}
```

When loading the form, pass your data object to the form and it will be available anywhere within this form

Comment: I am trying to get the data from Data, not set the data.

Comment: The data is set from another class.

Comment: you need to have access to your Data object within the class `Actions`. Where is the object containing your data stored?

Comment: @rohanharrison check edit. Another way I can think of(but you won't like it) would be to serialize your Data object situated in another class and deserialize it i, your form

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Data property to the form.

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Actions : Form
    {
        public Data Data { get; set; }

        private void Actions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testLabel.Text = data.State;
        }
    }
```

Elsewhere, if you already have a Data object `dat`

```
        var actionForm = new Actions();
        actionForm.Data = dat;
```

Comment: What if I set the Data values in a previous class, and I am just trying to get those values now?

Comment: You could add a `Data` property to the form.  Then set it after you create the form.  If the form will always require a `Data` member, you could inititalize it the constructor as demonstrated in @Sergey's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out.

I was doing the right thing initially, but I needed to make my Data class public.

My Code is:

```
public partial class Actions : Form
{
    public Actions(Data data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testLabel.Text = data.State;
    }
}


public class Data
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
```